# Discrete difference operator for a Matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix

```
A <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4, Byrow = FALSE)
```

I want a row-wise difference of matrix A. That is take element-wise difference between the first and second rows of A, element-wise difference between the second and third rows of A, etc. Since A ∈ R4×4, the resulting matrix should contain row-wise differences which has a dimension of 3 × 4.

Instead of using for-loop to iterate over the rows of A and take differences between consecutive rows, I would like to use the discrete difference operator to speed up the operation. I use sapply() to construct this matrix difference operator B. Then use B × A to compute the row-wise difference.

Let's say Matrix B ∈ R3×4

```
B <- matrix(c( -1,  1, 0,  0, 
                0, -1, 1,  0,
                0, 0, -1, 1), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Expected output be a matrix C ∈ R3×4 with all 1's.

```
Result_C <- matrix(c(  1, 1, 1,  1, 
                       1, 1, 1,  1,
                       1, 1, 1, 1), nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

How should I proceed? and what is difference operator for a Matrix in R?

Comment: Not clear about the use of `B` for computing the 'A' difference.  Why can't we just do `diff(A)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `diff` to calculate the difference between the rows

```
diff(A)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Yes, but what should we do with Matrix B?

Answer (score 0):

You can adress to full columns or rows of the matrix

```
A <- matrix(1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

A[2:(nrow(A)),]-A[1:(nrow(A)-1),]
```

and yes, `diff(A)` should do the same here